# Ruby append string to each element in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on analytics ruby api client. When making a call i am sending the params as

```
dimensions = ["ga:hostName", "pagePath"]
metrics = ["pageValue", "ga:pageviews"]
.call_analytics(dimensions, metrics)
```

Even if the user does not enter "ga:" when passing params, the code should append "ga:" in the params.

I have done it this way.

```
dimensions = dimensions.map{|a| ("ga:" + a.split(":").last).split}.flatten
metrics = metrics.map{|a| ("ga:" + a.split(":").last).split}.flatten
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What is the `split` after `last)` for?

Comment: @sawa: I want to convert it back into an array. That is the reason i used split

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
["ga:hostName", "pagePath"]
.map{|s| s.sub(/\A(?!ga:)/, "ga:")}
#=> ["ga:hostName", "ga:pagePath"]

["pageValue", "ga:pageviews"]
.map{|s| s.sub(/\A(?!ga:)/, "ga:")}
#=> ["ga:pageValue", "ga:pageviews"]
```

or

```
["ga:hostName", "pagePath"]
.map{|s| s.start_with?("ga:") ? s : s.prepend("ga:")}
#=> ["ga:hostName", "ga:pagePath"]

["pageValue", "ga:pageviews"]
.map{|s| s.start_with?("ga:") ? s : s.prepend("ga:")}
#=> ["ga:pageValue", "ga:pageviews"]
```

Comment: I would prefer using `map!`

Comment: This appends the string to the "original" array. What if I want to append a string, and store the result into a new array, and KEEP the original array?